# Suggestions for hoarding strategy and technics

Tags: coldstorage, storage

I've finally managed to figure out bitcoin, it's fantastic, now I have a goal of buying some coins while they're still affordable.

Please provide some advice for a fellow hoarder.
Just keeping all the sum in one wallet on a home PC is dangerous - what are the best ways to spread the storage? Physical bitcoins? Can you print one on paper (QR perhaps) and stash it somewhere? When keeping wallet on a removable media (e.g. flash drive), how many copies should I make? Should I even bother?

What's your favourite approach to keeping bitcoins you're not planning to spend right now?

Hints on the general strategy - how much to buy, how often, when to sell - are welcome too. Currently I plan to buy a few coins I can afford without noticing - a dinner worth of coins per month perhaps?

Comment: For storing them, I recommend a [paper wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet)

Comment: I recommend storing them in a blockchain.info wallet, making some backup copies of course.

Comment: I recommend storing your wallet on one of these http://www.ironkey.com/en-US/